# JSF (Joint Strike Fighter) like standard for C

Tags: c, coding-style

There is the well-known [Joint Strike Fighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-35_Lightning_II) (JSF) standard for C++. Is there a similar standard for C which promotes the use of C programmers' quality when coding for mission-critical platform?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for an embedded C coding style?

Comment: If so, this one is reasonable: http://www.barrgroup.com/Coding-Standard-Muse

Comment: The standard (2005): *[Joint Strike Fighter C++ coding standards](https://www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is [MISRA C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) by the Motor Industry Software Reliability Association:

[MISRA-C:2004](http://www.misra.org.uk), *Guidelines for the use of the C language in critical systems*

Answer (score 4):

[Les Hatton](http://www.leshatton.org/category/scientific-writing/safer-subsets/) has specified an ISO C subset for critical systems and has written quite a bit about [MISRA C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C). I'd read through (at least most of) what he has to say before making any decisions.

If you're in TLDR mode, the short answer is that most such guidelines (including MISRA C) include rules running the entire gamut from extremely useful to somewhat useful, to a few that are probably actively harmful (e.g., editing code to follow them is more likely to introduce bugs than fix anything).

Comment: The link is broken (*"Not Found. The requested URL /category/scientific-writing/safer-subsets/ was not found on this server."*).

Comment: Some candidates: *[Comments on MISRA C](https://www.leshatton.org/index_SA.html)*